# Losing values in JSON when passing to WEb API Action

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I have an object (A) with a few properties, one of which is a LIST of abother type (B).

I have a Web API Action that takes in an A object as a parameter.

I am just testing that I can pass this object via JSON son I have a webform with some Javascript on it as follows.......

```
    var tmpData = {
        lid: "f8fdb980-ccb8-4a54-9b83-b73dd2d569ca",
        aid: "8f6efc68-d747-42a4-b7d4-218951b66a97",
        bid: "e9f5e5d2-5d3d-41ac-89dc-7586ec2a5286",
        ps: []
    };
    tmpData['ps'].push({ "cid": "5a664dcc-8281-41f1-b81c-ae49499e12b8", "d": 5, "q": 2 });
    tmpData['ps'].push({ "cid": "4e9a30e0-c741-4708-88d7-8db4941c17cc", "d": 10, "q": 2 });

    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(tmpData);

    //Call the action to get the list in JSON format
    url = "http://localhost:64878/home/TakeTestBasketAddItemsRequest";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: myJSON,
        success: function (resultantData) {
            var s = resultantData;
            pResults.innerHTML = s;
        }
    });
```

This gets to the action OK and the object has 2 items in the "ps" property.
Howeverm the values in these 2 items are lost and I am left with zeros / uninitialised values.

Whay am I losing the values of the list items?

For clarity - here is my Action also.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TakeTestBasketAddItemsRequest(ECodeBasketRequest model)
    {
        try
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine(String.Format("LocationBridgeId: {0}{1}", model.lid, Environment.NewLine));
            sb.AppendLine(String.Format("ApplicationBridgeId: {0}{1}", model.aid, Environment.NewLine));
            sb.AppendLine(String.Format("BasketId: {0}{1}", model.bid, Environment.NewLine));
            foreach (var p in model.ps)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(String.Format("CategoryBridgeId: {2} Denomination: {0} Quantity: {1}{3}", p.d, p.q, p.cid, Environment.NewLine));
            }
            return Content(sb.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Content(string.Format("Problem: {0}", ex.ToString()));
        }
    }
```

As I said, I am just testing at the moment so would love to get to the bottom of this.  Thanks in advace,
Ant

Comment: This what I get back from the action.....

LocationBridgeId: f8fdb980-ccb8-4a54-9b83-b73dd2d569ca 
ApplicationBridgeId: 8f6efc68-d747-42a4-b7d4-218951b66a97 
BasketId: e9f5e5d2-5d3d-41ac-89dc-7586ec2a5286 
CategoryBridgeId: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Denomination: 0 Quantity: 0 
CategoryBridgeId: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Denomination: 0 Quantity: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies all - but it seems I ommitted the content type....
contentType: "application/json"

It's misleading when some of the object is reconstruucted OK and the rest isn't....but hey ho - It's Friday and it's working..

Well hopefully it will help someone else out.......
So I now find that this works.....

```
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        **contentType: "application/json",**
        data: myJSON,
        success: function (resultantData) {
            var s = resultantData;
            pResults.innerHTML = s;
        }
```